# Gmapping in Rviz with Turtlebot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to work on the tutorial provided for gmapping with the Turtlbot and am having some difficulties. I am only getting a blank background when running

rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find turtlebot_navigation`/nav_rviz.vcg

I have posted a screenshot that contains both my rviz screen and my terminal running the gmap demo. The camera is showing the map+obstacle data as shown in my second screenshot.[Screenshot-2.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1337635007645949.png)

I have played a bit with the map settings and the background/grid to try and get something but to no avail. Any ideas?

[Screenshot.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13376345616084252.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34498/gmapping-in-rviz-with-turtlebot/) by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-21**:
Try changing the target_frame to something besides the fixed frame that is attached to the robot, such as base_link or base_footprint.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-05-21**:
If the above suggestion does not work, the camera may still not be pointing in the correct. If you are using Fuerte, you can hit the zero button in the Views window. In Electric, I typically zoom out completely (right clicked + drag down), realign (both clicked + drag), zoom in (left clicked + drag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I did face this issue. Try changing the Views to "Orbit" "FPS" and "TopDown Ortho". You might be able to view the map as you wished.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) on 2012-05-22**:
Thanks Karthik! Changed to Orbit and I can finally see. Did you run into your robot getting confused as to its location? My gmap is not looking at all like it should. I am having slight lag with gmap updates but controls are responsive (using keypad). I have synced times as well.

**Comment by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) on 2012-05-22**:
The turtlebot is detecting obstacles accurately at about a 2s lag but is not drawing the map correctly. I lapped it around my cubicle 6 times with no obstacles except two cabinets and the walls (made a makeshift door to block entrance).